# Gradle build with GCJ

Tags: gradle, gcj

I want to build a Java project with GCJ (https://gcc.gnu.org/java/).

Building a non-trivial project would require build automation. Gradle would be a good choice among many. Building a Java project with GCJ is not something standard Gradle plugin would do.

Before I start writing a custom plugin, I want to have some answers for questions below:

- Is there an effort similar to this build task?
- Is there a custom plugin for GCJ build task?

Comment: Before you go any further you need to see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4035538/207421) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821940/is-gcj-still-in-development)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying which compiler to use:

**1. In `gradle.properties`:**

```
In your HOME_DIRECTORY set org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory
```

**2. In your `gradle.build`**

```
compile.options.fork = true
compile.options.forkOptions.executable = /path_to_javac
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/950427